# GoLang mgo - mgo.ErrNotFound for find(...).All(...)

Tags: mongodb, go, error-handling, mgo

I have a GoLang code:

```
c.Find(selectQuery).All(&results)
if err == mgo.ErrNotFound {
// error handling
}
```

`selectQuery` value is not important here.

I never get error `ErrNotFound`. Even if the query doesn't match any results I don't get `ErrNotFound`. I get variable `result` with empty attributes. How should I change the code to handle `ErrNotFound` case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Query.All()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.All) never returns `mgo.ErrNotFound`, so it's useless to check for that. If there are no results, the length of `results` will be 0, so that's how you can detect that *if* there were no errors:

```
err := c.Find(selectQuery).All(&results)
if err != nil { {
    // error handling
    return
}
// If you must detect "not found" case:
if len(results) == 0 {
    // No results
}
```

`mgo.ErrNotFound` is used / returned by other methods, usually by those which ought to operate on a single document, such as [`Query.One()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One) or [`Query.Apply()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Apply).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

The interesting thing is that I never get 0 for len(results). If my query doesn't match any results I get:

[{Email: Name:}]

As a result my len(results) is equal to 1

Comment: @poulius Then likely you **do** have one result document, which has empty string as its `Email` and `Name` (or simply those fields are missing or incorrectly mapped).

Comment: oh sorry, yes, you re right, there is something weitd with my selectQuery